# Linq to SQL: How to get values added thru InsertOnSubmit but before SubmitChanges?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, insertonsubmit

Having trouble getting this. I need get the values that I have added to a table entity through the InsertOnSubmit method. However I have not yet invoked SubmitChanges on the table.

So, I have this in a loop: mdmDC.tblMDMListItems.InsertOnSubmit(listItemsTable);

But I'd like to query mdmDC.tblMDMListItems for some values entered so far, yet I cannot seem to do that. Even after that code above the count on mdmDC.tblMDMListItems is 0.

How can I get the values added before SubmitChanges?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataContext.GetChangeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) and the [`ChangeSet.Inserts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.inserts.aspx) property.

```
// db is DataContext
ChangeSet cs = db.GetChangeSet();
foreach(var item in cs.Inserts) {
    // do something
}
```

Note that `item` is not strongly-typed. In fact, it can not be because the `DataContext` could be tracking items of differing types corresponding to multiple tables.